# Install Nvidia development driver on optimus on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus, opencl

I wanted to use OpenCL under Windows 7. I've got everything set up (Cuda Toolkit 4), the nvidia card is compatible (GeForce 310M).

I've got a Acer Travelmate 8372 with optimus, and I've got a bios option where I can choose between `Switchable` and `Discrete` or something similar. But if I choose the discrete option, all of the rendering is done over the intel chip, it's not even listing the nvidia card in the device manager anymore.

In switchable mode I can not find an option to enable the nvidia card explicitely. Hence the CUDA OpenCL Platform is not available.

Also I'm a bit confused about driver versions. Acer provides a Version 8.16.11.8997 (from 2011/11/24), where as NVidia provides the latest driver version 285.62 (from 2011/10/24).
Why do these versions differ? Because of Optimus?

I can't install any of the drivers provided by nvidia, the setup is complaining about incompatible hardware.

**Edit**: As I read optimus itself cannot be disabled, because the Intel chip is the graphics gateway either way. So the question should be: How can I install the Nvidia development driver on my optimus system?

Comment: At least you're not trying to run linux. Optimus is like leprosy in linux.

Comment: Well actually the Bios switch is working as desired under Linux... It uses the Nvidia card explicitly.

Comment: And I was able to install the Nvidia development driver on Linux.

Comment: Yea. My laptop didnt have the toggle in the BIOS. Had to use Bumblebee.